# Where is the CSS tag "half left" defined in the HTML code?

Tags: css

I am studying the HTML and CSS at http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/.  In the source line 139 I see a line:

`<div class="half left">`

I studied both CSS files that they include but I dont see where "half left" is defined.  Where is this defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are defined in `kraken-core.css` file as:-

```
.half {
  width:490px;
}

.left {
  float:left;
}
```

In another word, this `div` has a width of 490px, floating to the left.

Answer (score 4):

I havent checked the site, but assuming you copied the `div` tag correctly there is no single class of "half left," instead there's two classes "half" and "left." The HTML `class` attribute takes a space-delimited sequence of class-names.

Comment: And with a tool like Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) it is really easy to find where it is defined.

Answer (score 2):

This means that it has two classes, `half` and `left`.

It will receive CSS rules for `.half` or `.left`.

Answer (score 2):

This means two different CSS classes are used to style this element, .half and .left .